# Changing ui from a background thread using tasks with and without a dispatcher

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I understand that tasks are executed in the background and that if we want to mess with the ui we need to use a dispatcher, but i've noticed this too:

i have a label called `lMain` and i've set it up to change it's content after 2 seconds, like this:

```
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => 
{
    lMain.Content = "NEW VALUE";
});
```

this, obviously won't work because of cross thread access, i usually fix this with using a dispatcher:

```
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    {
        lMain.Content = "NEW VALUE";
    });
});
```

lately i noticed a possibility to use a `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` too, like this:

```
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => 
{
    lMain.Content = "NEW VALUE";
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

My question is:
Does this mean that when i use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` the task is executed on the main thread, or the dispatcher is used aswell?

Comment: Please note: in WPF `async/await` does the context switch for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wpf, `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` will return an instance of `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` which captures the current `SynchronizationConext` at the time you call the method. It saves it and posts the work in the context.

In short `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` is an abstraction over `SynhronizationContext`; In this case it is `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` which internally uses`Dispatcher`. So you're using the `Dispatcher` indeed, but this time implicitly.

Worth noting that `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` should be called only from a thread where synchronization context is set. I mean in a thread where `SynchronizationContext.Current` is available. Otherwise, you'll get an exception. For example calling this method in threadpool thread will result in exception.

Typically you call it from UI thread -- which will have the instance of `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` set to `Current` property of SynchronizationContext.

Also worth noting that if you use async/await you don't need any of these. All of these details are hidden from you. It is recommended that you use async/await if you can.

Comment: clean, easy to understand answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic Glad you found it easy to understand. I recommend to read my answer again as I have edited several times. I hope now it looks better than what it was initially.

Answer (score 0):

While you *could* do this:

```
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => 
{
  lMain.Content = "NEW VALUE";
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

it's a *lot* simpler to do this:

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
lMain.Content = "NEW VALUE";
```

Comment: second one is a lot simpler but won't work because it uses another thread.

Comment: I searched a little bit more and yes, sorry. I was wrong. sorry for downvote too.
In this case, your solution is the most helpfull I think.

Comment: @Cenkisabi: Thanks! Don't worry about the dv - those kinds of things happen.